# .Net 4.0 throws Invalid Date Exception

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, .net-4.5

In .Net 1.1 ,the following code does not show any error.

```
Dim T As DateTime = "10\1\2010"
```

But in .Net 4.5 , the same code shows error saying "Unrecognised Date Format".
Why is this happening? Why does .Net 1.1  converts "10\1\2010" to "10/1/2010" implicitly but not .Net 4.5 . Can it made possible on .Net 4.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with Date seperator "\", you can use below code

```
        Dim culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone()
        culture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "\"
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture
        Dim T As DateTime = "10\1\2010"
```

Comment: Is it possible to define custom Date separator globally? (in my case , '\' to de default date separator)  , rather than having to specify culture at each and every instance?

Comment: I have updated my answer for that, here cloning the current culture  of application. I haven't tried but it should work

Comment: Updated the answer with working code, as CultureInfo.CurrentCulture is readonly, so you can set the CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture of the Thread.CurrentThread. It will make your earlier code executed as it is.